# How to download using wget one by one in a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, wget

I have following code written which downloads from a page:

```
import urllib2,os
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    page = urllib2.urlopen('http://somesite.com')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        if "tutorials" in a['href']:
            os.system('wget ' + a['href'])
```

The issue is above command is it downloads all links altogether from the page. I want to download videos one by one. Is that possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the subprocess.call module instead of os.system.

```
subprocess.call(['wget' , a['href']])
```

Comment: Will it download one by one?

Comment: yes, because subproccess.call waits until the thread is completely executed. Just have a go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite late here but I think this might help someone. How about using `os.system()` in a separate function and calling it every time in a loop?

like:

```
def helper(arg):
   if(os.system(arg) == 0):
        print(arg," completed")
        return None
```

and

```
for link in links:
    helper("wget "+link)
```

I think this will ensure the one-by-one download.
Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!